# R loop over dataframe to create new dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

Suppose i have several data frames

```
dfx01=data.frame(city=c("a","b","c","d"),yr=c(2000,2001,2003,2002))
dfx02=data.frame(city=c("a","e","c","d"),yr=c(2000,2001,2005,2002))
dfx012=data.frame(city=c("f","b","c","d"),yr=c(2000,2000,2001,2002))
dfx022=data.frame(city=c("f","b","c","g"),yr=c(2002,2000,2003,2001))
```

how should i output corresponding data frames x01,x02,x012,x022 that subsets only yr=2001?

i attempted lapply

```
dflist=list(dfx01,dfx02,dfx012,dfx022)
lapply(dflist, fun(x){subset(x,startyr=2000)})
```

But how to name 4 new data frame x01,x02,x012,x022? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call just needs to be changed a little. Try

```
lapply(dflist, subset, yr == 2000)
```

But I prefer `[` subsetting, because `subset` can have unintended results. Here's how to do that, and add new names at the same time. To set names similar to your data frame names, it's best to add names to the list first.

```
> dflist <- setNames(dflist, grep("dfx0", ls(), value = TRUE))
> setNames(lapply(dflist, function(x) x[x$yr==2001, ]), 
                  gsub("df", "", names(dflist)))
# $x01
#   city   yr
# 2    b 2001
# 
# $x012
#   city   yr
# 2    e 2001
# 
# $x02
#   city   yr
# 3    c 2001
# 
# $x022
#   city   yr
# 4    g 2001
```

Comment: thanks, this works great. one other issue is that instead of naming the output df1-4, i want to use the last few characters of original name, like dfx01, it'll be great if the new df is named x01. how should i do that?

Comment: and what kind of unintended results would subset get?

Comment: Much appreciated! @Richard Scriven

Comment: still yet, how to make the output 4 df instead of part of a list?

Comment: From the list result, use `list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Awesome. I've never used this before.really handy.