# loop over dataframes to create new dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I want to loop over all dataframes to create new dataframes with only unique values. This is my code for creating 1 new dataframe:

```
dflist <- list(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3 = df3)
udf1 = unique(df1)
```

I don't know whether I should use a loop or a function. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `lapply(dflist, unique)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R loop over dataframe to create new dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697583/r-loop-over-dataframe-to-create-new-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to keep the unique rows in each data frame I'd do something like this.

```r
lapply(seq_along(dflist), function(l, n, i) { 
  assign(paste0(n[[i]]), distinct(l[[i]]), envir = globalenv()) 
  }, l=dflist, n=names(dflist))
```